# How to know if classification model is predicting 1 or 0

Tags: logistic-regression

I have used logistic regression to predict whether customer is good(1) or bad(0). I got the accuracy .80 . How do i know whether model predicted 1 or 0 .Is it related to parameter of model1.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] (the 1 in the end in square bracket).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the model predictions here:

```
model1.predict(X_test)

array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

In a binary (good/bad or 1/0) model, predict_proba is the probability of 0 or 1 , the value that is calculated by your model, which is used along with a cutoff (which is 0.5 in the sklearn implementation and cannot be changed) to determine if the final prediction is 0 or 1

```
model1.predict_proba(X_test)[:,0] # probability the answer is 0

array([0.94009529, 0.96378774, 0.98951049, ..., 0.67607543, 0.97599932,
   0.82838031])


model1.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] # probability the answer is 1

array([0.05990471, 0.03621226, 0.01048951, ..., 0.32392457, 0.02400068,
   0.17161969])
```

since this is a binary model, both should add up to one.

The accuracy score is how many predictions were correct.

(correct_pred_0 + correct_pred_1)/total_predictions

If you remove the [:,1], you get the entire array:

```
model1.predict_proba(X_test)

        #col 1       col 2

array([[0.94009529, 0.05990471],
       [0.96378774, 0.03621226],
       [0.98951049, 0.01048951],
       ...,
       [0.67607543, 0.32392457],
       [0.97599932, 0.02400068],
       [0.82838031, 0.17161969]])
```

First column is the probability for 0 and the second column is the probability for 1

you can check the order of the classes using this:

```
model1.classes_,
```

for binomial, the default is like this:

```
array([0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanx four your answer . What if we don't pass [:,1] in predict_proba . What default value it takes?

Comment: @SHUBHAMKUMAR, my full response is added to my answer above. Easier to read that way. The "[:,1]" is taking a slice of an array.

Comment: thanks i got that , and one more thing , how do we know that first column is the probability for 0 and the second column is the probability for 1 (is there way to check it , or is it by default ?)

Comment: you can check the order of the classes using this: model1.classes_, for binomial, the default is like this: array([0, 1], dtype=int64)

Comment: Thank you so much , you cleared my doubts perfectly.

Comment: @SHUBHAMKUMAR if this answer helped you, don't forget to 'accept' it (with the little green "v" button) so that others know it's closed.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin ,  I can't find little green "v" button.

Comment: Look at the tour (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tour), there's an example there, right at the top